# DrawString and DrawRectangle using same X&Y start at different places

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing, system.drawing

I have the following code:

```
public void DrawLetter(int Cell, string Letter, int X, int Y)
{
   System.Drawing.Font fBody = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));

   Pencil.DrawString(Letter, fBody, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, X, Y);
   Pencil.DrawRectangle(new Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Red), X, Y, 10, 10);        
}
```

When I go through this twice and use 140,249 and 296,249 as co-ordinates the rectangle appears as I would expect in the correct position but the string appears a few pixels out and I can't work out why.

I put in the DrawRectangle to check that it was starting in the correct position and it is.  Am I doing something wrong in the DrawString? Also if I draw a D and a Z the width of the D is 10px and Z is 8px, I thought using Courier it would give me fixed width?

**UPDATE:** I looked at the sample on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) and here is a screenshot. Even though the DrawString is positioned at 0,0 you can see that the letter does not appear at 0,0. The rectangle does though.  There must be padding or something:

[image: Screenshot]

**UPDATE 2:** Using the following code seems to improve things although its not perfect:

```
StringFormat strFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
Pencil.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
Pencil.DrawString(measureString, stringFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0), strFormat);
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: According to the your MSDN link: `The MeasureString method is designed for use with individual strings and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string to allow for overhanging glyphs. Also, the DrawString method adjusts glyph points to optimize display quality and might display a string narrower than reported by MeasureString. ` So, it looks like you have system offset during string drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't be the default padding / line-height etc being taken into account for the "Courier New" font would it?

Comment: I dont know, I'm pretty new to this. How do you combat it?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can, each drawing of font will incur a certain degree of whitespace around the text depending on the font implementation. It might just be a case of working out a suitable positive / negative offset to your original coordinate to determine where you want the text drawn. It would also help if you can take a screenshot to demonstrate the issue to clarify what you are seeing.

Comment: @Jon: It looks like my original hypothesis was correct, you are basically seeing the padding / margin which surrounds the rendered text. It should be consistent though so, simply add / subtract an approprite offset to get it back into position.

Comment: I dont get why it does that though. Its not documented and if you say draw at 0,0 you dont want it to appear at 10,10. Surely there must be a way to specify no padding